# Corona SDK Storyboard doesn't transit into scenes

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am creating a main menu and I want to handle my scenes with  storyboard.

Here is my main.lua:

```
-- Hide status bar
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar);

-- Some global variables
local assetsPath = "media/"
local lettersPath = "media/letters/"

-- Initialize storyboard
local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local widget = require("widget")

-- Load first scene
storyboard.gotoScene("splashscene")
```

and here is my splashscene.lua:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
```

local bgimg, moratechlogo,text

local function onSceneTouch(self,event)

```
if event.phase == "began" then

    storyboard.goToScene("mainmenuscene", "fade", 400)

    return true
end
```

end

function scene:createScene(event)

```
local screenGroup = self.view

bgimg = display.newImage("media/splashBG.png",0,0)
moratechlogo = display.newImage("media/moratechgames.png", display.contentWidth/2 - 150, display.contentHeight/2 - 100)
screenGroup:insert(bgimg)
screenGroup:insert(moratechlogo)
moratechlogo.touch = onSceneTouch


text = display.newText("Tap here to continue...", display.contentWidth /2 - 76, display.contentHeight - 30)
text:setTextColor(255)
screenGroup:insert(text)

text.touch = onSceneTouch
```

end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view

end

function scene:exitScene( event )

`-- remove touch listener for image
text:removeEventListener( "touch", text )
moratechlogo:removeEventListener("touch",moratechlogo)

   end

function scene:destroyScene( event )


end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene`

But when I click/touch the text and/or the logo it doesn't transit to mainmenuscene.lua
Any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to add the eventlistener to the logo and text?

Comment: Yes, I did. But now it tells me: attempt to go to goToScene (a nil value).
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so apparently I forgot to add the eventlisteners to the logo and text in the enterScene method.
Also, I mistyped "gotoScene", i wrote "goToScene" instead.

Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `widget.newButton`
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html

The button has options for a label, background image and more!

`local widget = require( "widget" )`

`local button1 = widget.newButton {
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "button1",
    label = "Default",
    onPress = function() 
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scenes", {effect="someEffect", time=someTime )
}`

If you created any other functions like `storyboard.hide_someObject()` you can put it right below `storyboard.gotoScene` and it will happen `onPress` when you press the button